# How to use LIKE in SQL Query in where clause, but the value of LIKE will come from in other query?

Tags: sql, qsqlquery, sql-query-store

How to use LIKE in SQL Query in where clause, but the value of LIKE will come from in other query?
For example:

```
SELECT Code FROM TABLE1 where Code LIKE '(select top 1 Grade FROM TABLE2 WHERE Age>30)%'
```

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Why not join TABLE1 with TABLE 2 ? Can you post the tables' s create ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Why are you comparing a column called `Grade` to one called `Code`?  Why are you using `top` with no `order by`?  Very mysterious what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must concatenate the result of the subquery with the char `'%'`:

```
SELECT Code FROM TABLE1 where Code LIKE (select top 1 Grade FROM TABLE2 WHERE Age>30) || '%'
```

You may change the operator `||` with `+` if this is the concatenation operator of your database.
Or with the function `concat()`:

```
SELECT Code FROM TABLE1 where Code LIKE concat((select top 1 Grade FROM TABLE2 WHERE Age>30), '%')
```

Note that using `top 1` without `order by` does not guarantee that the result will be what you would expect.

Comment: Thank you so much forpas

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your tables

```
create table TABLE1
(
    Code varchar(50)
)

create table TABLE2
(
    Grade varchar(50),
    Age int
)
```

Adding stuffs

```
insert TABLE1 values ('AAE')
insert TABLE1 values ('BBM')

insert TABLE2 values ('AAE00001', 22)
insert TABLE2 values ('BBM22501', 31)
```

Query

```
select 
Code 
from
TABLE1 inner join TABLE2 on TABLE1.Code = LEFT(TABLE2.Grade, LEN(TABLE1.Code))
where Age > 30
```

Result

[image]

If it's something like that you want, **be aware that it's awful**. I don't help you, it's a not solution. You have to review your design.

Comment: This looks like the opposite of what he has (On his schema, it seems `TABLE1` has the big codes, and `TABLE2` has the prefixes)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would be using `top` without `order by`.  The normal solution is to use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.Code
FROM TABLE1 t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table2 t2
              WHERE t2.Age > 30 AND
                    t1.code LIKE t2.Grade + '%'
             );
```

This assumes that `+` is used for string concatenation.

I speculate that this is what you really want -- comparison to all values in `table2` rather than just some indeterminate value from a matching row.

Comment: I think he wants only records on TABLE1 that compare positively with a single "top" record (whatever record he thinks that means, since there's no `order by`), instead of matching with any record of Age>30. Of course, the question is unclear, so it's difficult to assume anything.

Comment: @CássioRenan . . . I don't think that is the case.  I think the OP is using `TOP 1` because otherwise the subquery would return more than one row.  It really makes no sense without an `ORDER BY`.